# Faster way to filter a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, filter

I have a large list of dicts (200,000+) and need to filter those dicts based on a key many times (~11,000). What is the fastest way to do this?

I am retrieving a list of dicts (olist), roughly 225,000 dicts, and am trying to filter those dicts based on a single key ('type'). Currently, I build a list of all 'type' present in the dicts and then iterate over it, filtering the dicts for every 'type'. My problem is it takes ~.3s to do this initial 'type' filter, which would require almost an hour to run. I use threading which is getting me down to just over 10min but I would like to be closer to half that. Bellow are the relevant snippets of my code, is there a faster way of doing this (either faster filter or more effective algorithm)?

```
tLim = threading.BoundedSemaphore(500)
...
olist = _get_co_(h)   ## this returns a list of ~225,000 dictionaries
idlist = list(set([d['type'] for d in olist]))    ## returns list of ~11,000
for i in idlist:
    t = Thread(target=_typeData_, args=(i,olist,cData))
    threads.append(t)

def _typeData_(i,olist,cData):
    tLim.acquire()   
    tList = list(filter(lambda x: x['type'] == i, olist))  ## takes ~0.3s
    do stuff with tList  ## takes ~0.01s
```

Please note, I've look at generator expressions but it seems like having to store and recall the results might be worse? I haven't tried it though and I'm not sure how I would implement it...

Also, increasing the semaphore does not improve time much, if at all.

Comment: Using a list comprehensions may be faster: `[x for x in olist if x['type'] == i]`.

Comment: This should help marginally: don't use `filter` with `lambda` combination, use an equivalent list-comprehension. `[x for x in olist if x['type' = i]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga are you saying change my code to 
    tList = [x for x in olist if x['type' = i]]
?

this doesn't seem to work (python 3.5.1)... nor does list(x for x...)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the dictionaries by type so you can avoid the `filter` later on:

```
from collections import defaultdict
id_groups = defaultdict(list)
for dct in olist:
    id_groups[dct['type']].append(dct)
```

now you don't need to filter at all, you just iterate over this `id_groups` and you'll get a list of all dictionaries of that type:

```
for i, tList in id_groups.items():
    # the i and tList are identical to your variables in the "_typeData_" function.
    # do something with tList
```